# Is it possible to use Java MiG Layout with the IntelliJ IDE?

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, miglayout

Most of the question is in the title but I've been using eclipse most of the time for my Java programming with the Windowbuilder Pro plugin. I've been wanting to try out IntelliJ with MiG Layout.

Does anyone know if this is indeed possible and how to accomplish this?

Comment: Mig layout is meant to be used programmatically, and that works in any IDE.

Comment: Ok, so I understand that I probably wont be able to use the WYSIWYG functionality like with the eclipse plugin since IntelliJ have their own swing designer, but how would I got about using the MiG layout? What do I need to import etc, do I need an external jar?

Comment: MiG layout support is [planned for JFormDesigner](http://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/features/roadmap/) that has IntelliJ IDEA integration, just FYI.

Comment: @CrazyCoder interesting, thanks for that information.

Comment: JFormDesigner is expensive